# Who creates EFI partition on a UEFI system?

Tags: linux-kernel, grub, uefi

Who creates `EFI` partition on a `UEFI` system and keep the `grub` exe there? Is that the `OS Distro` has this directory and later mounted while a first time installation on the `UEFI` machine?

Answer (score 2):

That's the job of any OS installer: If there's no EFI partition there already, you'll have to make one, or else your system can't boot *anything* in UEFI mode.

So, if the first OS that gets installed on your UEFI machine is Windows, it's the windows installer. If the first one is Linux, then that installer has to do it.

Or you do it yourself! There's really no magic involved there.

All second-stage bootloaders (be it the GRUB UEFI shim, be it the windows bootloader, be it memtest86+ (in the UEFI variant), or anything else) *share* that EFI partition; that's not a problem, you just put your bootloader image there, and tell UEFI it can boot from it. There can be many shims on that partitions, as long as their file names differ.

Comment: Not really, some BIOS have compability features to boot without ESP. And yes, ESP can be created for any reason, finding who created it in the first place can be difficult enough. This answer doesnt really give a way to find the "who" in the question

Comment: sure, but we're talking about an UEFI system, not about a system emulating BIOS. Clarified my first sentence.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 and the original question does not ask who *created* a specific partition in the past, it asks who *creates* the partition, i.e., whose job it is to create the partition.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you please clear this , In your answer's second paragraph it says, if it is Linux, then the linux installer would create the UEFI. That is really my question is. Which module is that "installer". I know it is neither grub nor initrd modules nor vmlinux. Or is that the UEFI module(first level boot loader) in mother board does that creation of ESP?

Comment: it's the installer. Different operating systems (and operating system distros) bring different installers.